# Sessão PHP com tempo de redirecionamento

Tags: php, session, redirect

Preciso de ajuda em relação a um script de sessão de usuário em PHP com tempo tempo de espera,de forma que se não houver atividade na pagina ela seja redirecionada para uma página de saída.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Após o usuário efetivar o login, você pode inserir o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    session_cache_expire(1800); //o tempo é medido em segundos

?>
```

Desta forma, toda página que necessitar da sessão de usuário, você deve verificar se há uma sessão de usuário ativa, assim:

```
<?

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){

        //aqui você aplica o redirecionamento
        header("Location: ".$enderecoPagina);
    }

?>
```

Comment: é automático amigo? em tempo real?

Comment: Estou meio confuso em relação ao seu "automático", você quer dizer que ao estourar o tempo já redirecione a página, ou se o usuário tentar ir para uma página que precisa de sessão e ela já esgotou, logo teria que redirecionar?

Comment: consegui com javascript

Comment: em tempo real mesmo